# Migrating from SpringFox to SpringDoc problem with SwaggerConfig

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security

I updated project from java 12 to 17 and after I updated and migrated whole project, now it's turn to rewrite configuration for spring security. This is my swagger config and he should be replaced with OpenAPI config.

```
public class SwaggerConfig {

    private final String API_AUTH_SCHEME_NAME = "API Bearer Token";
    private final String BASIC_AUTH_SCHEME_NAME = "basicAuth";

    @Profile("!security")
    @Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return basicApi();
    }

    @Profile("security")
    @Bean
    public Docket securedApi() {
        return basicApi()
            .securitySchemes(Arrays.asList(authEndpointScheme(), apiEndpointAuthScheme()))
            .securityContexts(Arrays.asList(authEndpointSecurityContext(), apiEndpointSecurityContext()));
    }

    private SecurityContext authEndpointSecurityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder()
            .securityReferences(Collections.singletonList(authEndpointReference()))
            .forPaths(PathSelectors.ant("/api/auth/token"))
            .build();
    }

    private SecurityContext apiEndpointSecurityContext() {
        return SecurityContext.builder()
            .securityReferences(Collections.singletonList(apiAuthEndpointReference()))
            .forPaths(PathSelectors.regex("/api/(?!auth).*"))
            .build();
    }

    private SecurityScheme authEndpointScheme() {
        return new BasicAuth(BASIC_AUTH_SCHEME_NAME);
    }

    private SecurityScheme apiEndpointAuthScheme() {
        return new ApiKey(API_AUTH_SCHEME_NAME, HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "header");
    }

    private SecurityReference authEndpointReference() {
        return new SecurityReference(BASIC_AUTH_SCHEME_NAME, new AuthorizationScope[0]);
    }

    private SecurityReference apiAuthEndpointReference() {
        return new SecurityReference(API_AUTH_SCHEME_NAME, new AuthorizationScope[0]);
    }
```

Now I have to replace this config with OpenAPI config with springdoc.
Can someone help me?

Comment: i think you should to check it [migrating-from-springfox](https://springdoc.org/migrating-from-springfox.html)